# Test Fax Machine

Tags: fax, magicjack

I just bought a fax machine and I want to test it, but I don't have a regular phone line.  I am not confident that it will work on my Magic Jack.  A quick search on turned up [this article for sending a test fax to a service provided by HP](http://www.ehow.com/how_7335740_receive-test-fax.html).

Will this work with a Magic Jack?  Is there a better way to test faxing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that 888-HPFaxMe works great, even with Magic Jack.  For some reason it didn't work the first time I sent it, but it did work the second time.  I sent the fax to 888-HPFaxMe after setting my printer to the lowest baud rate it allowed.  After the second time, I got a fax back that looked great.

I'm posting this answer in the hopes that it will help anyone else with the same question.